# accessing a global memory pointer from a CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

I am attempting to allocate device memory and store the pointer as a global variable. However, when I attempt to access the memory from a kernel, I receive this error from cudaDeviceSynchronize(): **cudaErrorIllegalAddress**. I've checked the cudaStatus codes returned from cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy and they are both successful.

I hope the following example is straight forward enough to demonstrate what I want to do. Basically, I have a large array of sample data that I want all the kernels to be able to read from, but I don't want to have to pass the pointer into the kernel call every time.

I'm using Windows 8 x64, compiling code with Visual Studio 2012 and nvcc (via VS integration). Target is x64 Debug executable. My device is a GTX 780.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE (1024 * 1024 * 10)

__device__ int* cData;

void Init()
{
    int* data = new int[SIZE];
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&cData, SIZE * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        data[i] = i;

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(cData, data, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    delete data;
}

__global__ void kernel(int i, int* output)
{
    *output = cData[i];
}

int main()
{
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaDeviceProp properties;
    int* result;
    cudaStatus = cudaMallocManaged(&result, sizeof(int));
    Init();

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(1000, result); // invoke a single thread, expecting the value of *result to be 1000 afterwards
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // returns cudaErrorIllegalAddress

    printf("Value is: %d", *result); // crashes the program, "In page error reading location 0x0000000D00000000"
    cudaFree(result);
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cData` resides on the device, but `cudaMalloc` requires the pointer to be on the host (and pointing to device memory).

Answer (score 5):

We don't use `cudaMalloc` and  `cudaMemcpy` on `__device__` variables.

Read [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) for `__device__` variables, where it states the API calls to be used:

```
 cudaMemcpyToSymbol();
 cudaMemcpyFromSymbol();
```

If you want to use `cudaMalloc` on a dynamically allocated device array, but store the returned pointer in a `__device__` variable, you'll have to do something like this:

```
void Init()
{
    int* data = new int[SIZE];
    int* d_data;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&d_data, SIZE * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        data[i] = i;

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cData, &d_data, sizeof(int *));
    delete data;
}
```

When I compile your code as-is, I get the following compiler warning from CUDA 6 `nvcc`:

```
t411.cu(15): warning: a __device__ variable "cData" cannot be directly read in a host function
```

Those warnings should not be ignored.

If `SIZE` is known at compile-time, as it is in your example, you can also do something like this:

```
__device__ int cData[SIZE];

void Init()
{
    int* data = new int[SIZE];
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        data[i] = i;
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cData, data, SIZE * sizeof(int));
    delete data;
}
```