# cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy not working on kernel call

Tags: memory, cuda

I have an array already initialized that I am trying to use in each thread of the kernel call (each thread uses a different part of the array so there are no dependencies). I create the array and save memory on the device using `cudaMalloc` and the array is copied from host to device using `cudaMemcpy`.

I pass the pointer returned by `cudaMalloc` to the kernel call to be used by each thread.

```
int SIZE = 100;

int* data = new int[SIZE];
int* d_data = 0;

cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc(&d_data, SIZE * sizeof(int)) );
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    data[i] = i;

cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
```

This code was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970881/accessing-a-global-memory-pointer-from-a-cuda-kernel).
For the kernel call.

```
kernel<<<blocks, threads>>> (results, d_data);
```

I keep track of the results from each thread by using the struct `Result`. The next code works without errors.

```
__global__ void mainKernel(Result res[], int* data){
   int x = data[0];
}
```

But when I assign that value to `res`:

```
__global__ void mainKernel(Result res[], int* data){
   int threadId = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

   int x = data[0];

   res[threadId].x = x;
}
```

An error is raised:

> cudaSafeCall() Runtime API error in file , line 355 : an illegal memory access was encountered.

The same error appears with any operation involving the use of that pointer

```
__global__ void mainKernel(Result res[], int* data){
   int threadId = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

   int x = data[0];

   if (x > 10)
      res[threadId].x = 5;
}
```

There is no problem with the definition of `res`. Assigning any other value to `res[threadId].x` does not give me any error.

This is the output of running cuda-memcheck:

> ========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
>   =========     at 0x00000150 in mainKernel(Result*, int*)
>   =========     by thread (86,0,0) in block (49,0,0)
>   =========     Address 0x13024c0000 is out of bounds
>   =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
>   =========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1   (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x150d6d]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x2cc4b]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x46c23]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x3e37]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x3ca1]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x3cd6]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x39e9]
>   =========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21ec5]
>   =========     Host Frame:./out [0x31b9]

EDIT:

This is an example of the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct    
{
   int x,y,z;
} Result;

__global__ void mainKernel(Result  pResults[], int* dataimage)
{

   int threadId = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

   int xVal = dataimage[0];
   if (xVal > 10)
       pResults[threadId].x = 5;

}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

   int NUM_THREADS = 5*5;

   int SIZE = 100;

   int* data = new int[SIZE];
   int* d_data = 0;

   cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc(&d_data, SIZE * sizeof(int)) );
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       data[i] = i;

   cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

   unsigned int GPU_ID = 1;  // not actually :-)
   // unsigned int GPU_ID =  cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId() ;
   cudaSetDevice(GPU_ID); 

   Result * results_GPU = 0;
   cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc( &results_GPU,  NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result)) );

   Result * results_CPU = 0;
   cutilSafeCall( cudaMallocHost( &results_CPU, NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result)) );

   mainKernel<<<5,5>>> ( results_GPU, d_data );

   cudaThreadSynchronize(); 

   cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(results_CPU, results_GPU, NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

   cutilSafeCall(cudaFree(results_GPU));
   cutilSafeCall(cudaFreeHost(results_CPU));
   cudaThreadExit();

 } // ()
```

Comment: The problem is clearly with `results`, and yet you have managed to completely omit all the code that shows how you have defined and allocated it. Could you edit your question to include a short, complete code which someone else could compile and run? Without it, it will be very difficult to give you any sort of answer to your question

Comment: To be clear, that exact code produces the error you posted? How many CUDA GPUs do you have?

Comment: Yes it does (you have to include the CudaSafeCall). I have two GPUs. I removed the lines for selecting the GPU (cudaSetDevice) and It does not raise any error. What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this sequence of calls:

```
  cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc(&d_data, SIZE * sizeof(int)) );
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       data[i] = i;

   cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

   unsigned int GPU_ID = 1;
   cudaSetDevice(GPU_ID); 

   Result * results_GPU = 0;
   cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc( &results_GPU,  NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result)) );

   Result * results_CPU = 0;
   cutilSafeCall( cudaMallocHost( &results_CPU, NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result)) );

   mainKernel<<<5,5>>> ( results_GPU, d_data );
```

What is effectively happening is that you are allocating `d_data` and running your kernel on different GPUs, and `d_data` is not valid on the GPU you are launching the kernel on.

In detail, because you call `cudaMalloc` for `d_data` before `cudaSetDevice`, you are allocating `d_data` on the *default* device, and then explicitly allocating `results_GPU` and running the kernel on device 1. Clearly device 1 and the default device are not the same GPU (enumeration of devices usually starts at 0 in the runtime API).

If you change the code like this:

```
   unsigned int GPU_ID = 1;
   cutilSafeCall(cudaSetDevice(GPU_ID)); 

   cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc(&d_data, SIZE * sizeof(int)) );
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       data[i] = i;

   cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, SIZE * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

   Result * results_GPU = 0;
   cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc( &results_GPU,  NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result)) );

   Result * results_CPU = 0;
   cutilSafeCall( cudaMallocHost( &results_CPU, NUM_THREADS * sizeof(Result)) );

   mainKernel<<<5,5>>> ( results_GPU, d_data );
```

i.e. select the non-default device before any allocations are made, the problem should disappear. The reason this doesn't happen with your very simple kernel:

```
__global__ void mainKernel(Result res[], int* data){
   int x = data[0];
}
```

is simply that the CUDA compiler performs very aggressive optimisations by default, and because the result of the read of `data[0]` isn't actually used, the entire read can be optimised away and you are left with an empty stub kernel which doesn't do anything. Only when the result of the load from memory is used in a memory write will the code not be optimised away during compilation. You can confirm this yourself by dissassembling the code emitted by the compiler, if you are curious.

Note that there are ways to make this work on multi-GPU systems which supported it, via peer-to-peer access, but that must be explicitly configured in your code for that facility to be used.